# Storing 32 bit keys in java keystore

Tags: java, security, keystore

How can I store 32 bit key in java keystore against my alias, I tried:

```
keytool -genseckey -keystore aes-keystore.jck -storetype jceks -storepass mystorepass  -keysize 32 -alias jceksaes -keypass mykeypass
```

But I get error:

```
keytool error: java.security.InvalidParameterException: Wrong keysize: must be equal to 56
```

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be trying to generate an AES key, so you need to specify the `-keyalg` parameter with an appropriate value. The default is "DES". See the [keytool documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/tools/windows/keytool.html).